# Drag and drop an bitmap image on android phone screen

Tags: android

Drag and drop an bitmap image on android phone screen,i have a canvas i am drawing my bitmap and now i want to drag and drop the image and implements its action after dropping the image on a particular location..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html). It is Android D&D framework.